# How can I fix the error "failed to initialize projection" on Mapnik?

Tags: mapnik

I have the "failed to initialize projection" problem in the current mac version 3.1.0.

The error text:

```
RuntimeError: failed to initialize projection with: '&srs900913;'
```

In older issues you can read: mapnik "use rapidxml instead of libxml2. Only libxml2 supports XML entities" ([mapnik/node-mapnik#279](https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/issues/279#issuecomment-46765824) (comment))

One solution is merge all the include files in on file, than the brew version work. But this is very bad!!!

One solution is compile the mapnik self on my mac. But if I do this, how can I link on the compilation process lib libxml2 not rapidxml?

Why is on brew no libxml2 version? Or is anywhere such version?

Comment: Nobody should use the fake EPSG code EPSG:900913 any more. Use the official EPSG:3857 instead. The reason for the issue may be that your new Mac installation does not know the meaning of EPSG:900913. Edit the Mapnik configuration file by find and replacing and have a new try.

Comment: The reason of the problem is brew mapnik can't resolve mapnik-include files see details https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/issues/279#issuecomment-46765824
I need therefore a mapnik version with libxml2 and brew mapnik have only rapidxml.